# How to redirect with authenticated user in thymeleaf?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-thymeleaf

I have a custom login page.
My Controller contains something like that:

```
@PostMapping
public String doLogin(@ModelAttribute Nutzer nutzer) {
//Verify user in Database
if(exists) {
return "redirect:/overview";
}
return "redirect:Login";
```

The overview redirect endpoint Looks like that.

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('User')
@GetMapping("overview")
public String getOverview(Model model) {
//add Userdetails to model. 
return "overview"
```

Preauthorization fails, cause redirecting as anonymousUser.
How can I set the authentication to this redirect?
Is it possible?

I'll tried to get SecurityContext and set a UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken with username, password and authority as authentication. Setting Log Level to debug.
But it doesn't work, in Logs I can see, the SecurityContext ist Setting back to anonymousUser.

Comment: What Spring Security version are you using?

Comment: Using spring-boot-starter-security:3.0.4 (spring-security-core:6.0.2)